# Best way to calculate the nearest point from another point?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, drawing

I have four point say `_pointA` `_pointB` `_pointC` `_pointD`. I want to find the nearest point from the current point. I had something like this but it sometimes gives wrong reasult.

Problem : When i near to `pointA` it gives `pointC`

```
 CGPoint neastPoint=CGPointZero;
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
    CGFloat x;
    CGFloat y;
    CGFloat currntDistance;
    if (i==0){
        x=(pointA.x-currentPoint.x) *(pointA.x-currentPoint.x);
        y=(pointA.y-currentPoint.y)*(pointA.y-currentPoint.y);
        currntDistance =sqrtf(x+y);
        distance=currntDistance;
        neastPoint=pointA;

    }
    else if (i==1){
        x=(pointB.x-currentPoint.x) *(pointB.x-currentPoint.x);
        y=(pointB.y-currentPoint.y)*(pointB.y-currentPoint.y);
        currntDistance =sqrtf(x+y);
        if (distance>currntDistance) {
            distance=currntDistance;
            neastPoint=pointB;
        }
    }
    else  if (i==2){
        x=(pointC.x-currentPoint.x) *(pointC.x-currentPoint.x);
        y=(pointC.y-currentPoint.y)*(pointC.y-currentPoint.y);
        currntDistance =sqrtf(x+y);
        if (distance>currntDistance) {
            distance=currntDistance;
            neastPoint=pointC;
        }
    }
    else {
        x=(pointD.x-currentPoint.x) *(pointD.x-currentPoint.x);
        y=(pointD.y-currentPoint.y)*(pointD.y-currentPoint.y);
        currntDistance =sqrtf(x+y);
        if (distance>currntDistance) {
            distance=currntDistance;
            neastPoint=pointD;
        }

    }



 CurrentPoint : {44, 33.140846}
Point A : {71, 178}
Point B : {134, 178}
Point C : {133, 71}
Point D : {75, 67}
Nearast Point  : {133, 71}
```

Comment: Your code is VERY inefficient (you could get rid of the `for` and all the `if`s, and using an array would be even better), but it should work. What is exactly the problem?

Comment: Well to start, encapsulate your if-block body into a common function. Then I would put the points in a list and iterate over them to find the one with the least distance. It probably works as is though.

Comment: You're using pointB.y in your first if statement instead of pointA.y, is this an error here or is this in your code as well?

Comment: yaa its working but there is something problem because i can't get pointA if it current point is close to pointA

Comment: @Logan it was my mistake for posting code but its pointA in my code

Comment: Have you tried to *debug* your problem? If you have a case where you don't get the expected result then it should be simple to single-step through your code and find the problem.

Comment: @Merlevede yes it is that's why i posted for the simplest way

Comment: @MartinR yes i did when i near to pointA it gives pointC i don/t know why?

Comment: @Sunnyshah Just to make sure, this is not the code you're actually running, this is a simplified version for us?

Comment: @Merlevede yes man i am sure i had updated my question i shown you the console output

Comment: yes poine C but it should be pointA

Comment: Actually the nearest point is D

Comment: Point C is closer than A, If the values you gave are correct, then point C is in fact closer than A and D is the closest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the points that you have given, `pointD` is the closest to `currentPoint`.
It is not found by your code because

```
for (int i=0; i<3; i++) {
```

should be

```
for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {
```

to check all 4 points. As others have noticed, you can simplify your code,
for example

```
CGFloat distance = FLT_MAX; // start with some large value 
CGPoint nearestPoint;

CGPoint points[] = { pointA, pointB, pointC, pointD };
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    CGFloat currentDistance = hypotf(points[i].x - currentPoint.x, points[i].y - currentPoint.y);
    if (currentDistance < distance) {
        distance = currentDistance;
        nearestPoint = points[i];
    }
}
```

Comment: yaaa you are right but when i got it return point C so there will be some problem with code that i cant understand

Comment: @Sunnyshah: I have tested the code with *your values*, and it returned pointD, which is the closest to currentPoint.

Comment: @Sunnyshah: Sorry, there was an error which I have fixed now.

Comment: i just removed my code and used yours it works find.. thanks:-)

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo :

```
Point[] allPoints = {poinA,pontB,pointC,....,pointN}

int distance = Int.MAX_VALUE;
Point nearestPoint = null;

for(int i = 0 ; i < allPoints.count;i++){
     if(pointA != allPoints[i]){
      int currentDistance = getDistance(pointA,allPoints[i]);
       if(currentDistance < distance){
          distance = currentDistance;
          nearestPoint = allPoints[i];
       }
     }
   }

print("Nearest point is " + nearestPoint);
```

Comment: Where is the getDistanse() declaration? Also, using integers for this probably isn't a good idea in case the points are close.

Comment: @Logan, thats just pseudo, QA alredy know how to implement  `getDistance()` it's implementation(duplicated few times) can be seen in question